# For each $x$ in a Hilbert $A$-module $X$, there exists a unique $y\in X$ such that $x=y\langle y,y \rangle $.

Tags: functional-analysis, modules, c-star-algebras

How do I prove this lemma?

Lemma: Suppose that $X$ is a Hilbert $A$-module. For each $x\in X$ there exists a unique $y\in X$ such that $x=y \langle y,y \rangle $.

I don't know if this is needed but we already know Cohen's factorization theorem that states If $A$ is a Banach algebra with a bounded left or right approximate identity, then for all $a\in A$ there exist $b,c \in A$ such that $a=bc$.

Comment: If $\langle x,x\rangle$ is invertible you can set $y=x\langle x,x\rangle^{1/3}$

Comment: @Norbert: You mean $-1/3$, right?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, you are right. Do you have any ideas for the general case?

Comment: @Norbert: I cheated, i.e., I knew where to look it up.  It is Proposition 2.31 in Raeburn and Williams's *Morita equivalence and continuous trace $C^*$-algebras*.  They cite the article at the following link as the source of the proof they present (link to large pdf, where the result is found on the sixth page, a.k.a. page 145): http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1996__124_1/BSMF_1996__124_1_141_0/BSMF_1996__124_1_141_0.pdf

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks!

Comment: @JonasMeyer May be you should write this comment as an answer. I think this is a bad practice to post answers as comments

Comment: @Norbert: I am not interested in doing so at the moment, but you and all others are free to do so.  It is not a very good answer for those who don't have access to the book and don't read French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the book *[Morita equivalence and continuous trace C*-algebras](http://books.google.com/books?id=KV_cC5uYA7EC)* by I. Raeburn and D. Williams, you will find this proved there as Proposition 2.31 on [page 21](http://books.google.com/books?id=KV_cC5uYA7EC&pg=PA21) (the proof is on the next page).  In [this 6 MB pdf file](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1996__124_1/BSMF_1996__124_1_141_0/BSMF_1996__124_1_141_0.pdf) of the article "Déformations de C*-algèbres de Hopf" by E. Blanchard, the result is on the sixth page (labeled as page 145 in the publication).